# Can a pipe (from pipe syscall) have bi-directional communication?

Tags: c

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html:

> Data can be written to the file descriptor fildes[1] and read from the
>   file descriptor fildes[0]. A read on the file descriptor fildes[0]
>   shall access data written to the file descriptor fildes[1] on a
>   first-in-first-out basis. It is unspecified whether fildes[0] is also
>   open for writing and whether fildes[1] is also open for reading.

As I understand, when you call the pipe syscall like `pipe(array)`, then `array[0]` is for reading and `array[1]` is for writing. However, can they both be for read and write?

I know I can create another pipe to get write/read in the reverse direction, but can it be done in the same pipe? What the document means with

> It is unspecified whether ...

Comment: A pipe is a one-way channel, and though I suppose one could have the same process read and write to itself, that's not really what it's for. If you want another one-way channel, you have to make a second pipe (or: you could use UNIX domain sockets, which are a bidirectional channel that works like a network connection).

Comment: Bi-directional pipes only work on BSD. If you want to do a bi-directional pipe portably, use a unix domain [socket pair](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand, when you call the pipe syscall like `pipe(array)`, then
>   `array[0]` is for reading and `array[1]` is for writing.

Yes.

> However, can they
>   both be for read and write?

No, the `pipe()` function does not provide for that, unless as an extension.  A standard pipe is a unidirectional communication channel.

If great care is exercised, however, then a single pipe may be  usable for bidirectional communication.  Any number of threads or processes may write to the write end of the pipe, and any number of the same or other threads or processes may read from the read end.  Under most circumstances, however, reliable bidirectional communication over a single pipe by reliance on these characteristics requires more synchronization and coordination than it is worth.

For bidirectional communication, the usual approach is to create *two* pipes, one for each direction.  You could also consider a [`socketpair()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) -- this seems to be less common, but it yields a situation more like what you probably had in mind: two file descriptors, one for each endpoint of a bidirectional communication channel.

Comment: Thanks. I'm asking that because I need to pass to OpenVPN a file descriptor that has both write/read properties. This file descriptor is passed in the place of a file descriptor for /dev/net/tun. OpenVPN uses this FD as a way to write and read IP packets. Given that in mind, which type of socketpair I should open? Here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html it show the 3 types, but I'm not sure which one is the rigth one.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, I haven't enough information on OpenVPN's requirements to answer confidently, but *probably* a socket of type `SOCK_STREAM` would have the appropriate characteristics.  That's not the only parameter you need to choose, however. You also need to choose which family of transports ("address family") to use, and for that I would suggest starting with `AF_UNIX`.